# datatable select filter where column timespan

Tags: c#, winforms, time

i want to ask, how do i set condition or expression where the column table is type of `timespan`.
when i use this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string expression2;
        expression2 = "timeOnlyStart < '" + TimeSpan.Parse("10:00:00") + "'";
        DataTable yyy = dt_Main.Select(expression2).CopyToDataTable();
        gridControl3.DataSource = yyy;
    }
```

it gives me error [image].

EDITED : timeOnlyStart is a column start

[image]

Comment: Probably you define the timeOnlyStart as varchar or nvarchar, because of that you receive this error.

Comment: What is the data type `timeOnlyStart` ?

Comment: iam not sure, from what i see is `time span`. i dont have any access of the sql server. the thing is the person in charge take a break for 1 day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to filter rows

```
var results = from myRow in dt_Main.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<TimeSpan>("timeOnlyStart") < TimeSpan.Parse("10:00:00")
              select myRow;
gridControl3.DataSource  = results.AsDataView();
```

if you need datatable

```
 var resultsdt = results.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: thx it works.
is there another way than using linq. never use linq before.. just curios :)

Comment: is there a way to store it in datatable ?, i need to parse the datatable to other form

Comment: @chopperfield Select expressions  can be used but with TimeSpan it is difficult  to compare. check my update for convert result back to DataTable